# Is this a varistor? WP 270M

Tags: identification, components, varistor

I can't figure out whether it's a varistor or any other non-polar capacitor.

Please also suggest how to test it.

[image: photo of unknown component]

Answer (score 2):

If it says "WP270M", then it's a thermistor; a Samsung PTC thermistor, 265 V, 27 Ω, 1.5 A, to be precise.

Exquisitely googleable.